# First time using cairo in AwesomeWM

Tags: cairo, awesome-wm

This is for anyone who's having trouble getting started with cairo.

The documentation didn't give a good, complete example. That's why I wanted to share this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a concrete example which you can put in your rc.lua and play with it.

```lua
local wibox = require('wibox')
local cairo = require("lgi").cairo

local surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.Format.RGB24,20,20)
local cr = cairo.Context(surface)

my_wbox = wibox()
my_wbox.visible = true
my_wbox:set_bg("#ff0000")

cairo_widget = wibox.widget.base.make_widget()
cairo_widget.fit = function(context, width, height) 
    return 100, 100
end
cairo_widget.draw = function(self, my_wbox, cr, width, height)
    cr:translate(100, 100)
    cr:set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
    cr:rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
    cr:fill()
end

my_wbox:set_widget(cairo_widget)
my_wbox:geometry({x=50, y=50, width=500, height=500})
```

Comment: Feel free to make a pull request on github to add it to the documentation. That would come helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/04-new-widgets.md.html, but I guess that page does not have a "here is everything in one copy-able chunk" at the end.

Comment: I know it's kind of stupid, but personally I struggled a bit to wrap my head around all this.
Especially that you need to use cairo on a wibox (I saw it somewhere in the documentation but can't find it now). You also need to set it visible because for some reason the default is false, same goes for background.

Comment: I don't think it's stupid. I think that is is stupid that I wrote half this code and thus never had to try to wrap my head around it, so I cannot really see most problems. It would be great if you improved the docs and it is totally fine to ask for help in learning.

Comment: For that "cairo on a wibox": Uhm, sorry, I don't feel I understand what you are trying to say. For the "default for visible is false": This is to prevent visual artifacts. If the default were `true`, the wibox would become visible before anything had a chance to set up its content. At least I believe this might be the reason, but I am not 100% sure...

Comment: Well the "cairo on a wibox" I meant that you can't draw cairo widget as standalone widgets. After `cairo_widget = wibox.widget.base.make_widget()` and declaring `fit` + `draw` functions I figured it would just appear on the screen.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well... dunno what to do about that. My best idea is "add a glossary" to the docs, but personally, I pretty much always skip glossaries when I come across one... Sorry, no good ideas.